# How can you directly output the result of a helper that takes a block in ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, block

I have a helper that takes a block:

```
def container(&block)
  render(:partial => 'layouts/container', :locals => {:content => capture(&block)})
end
```

When I try to use it inside a `<%= ... %>` tag in ERB:

```
<%= container do %>
  Test
<% end %>
```

I get a `compile error`:

```
compile error
test2.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')'
            old_output_buffer = output_buffer;;@output_buffer = '';  __in_erb_template=true ; @output_buffer.concat(( container do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat "\r\n"
                                                                                                                                    ^
test2.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
test2.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'
```

However, if I capture the output of the helper and then output it:

```
<% output = container do %>
  Test
<% end %>
<%= output %>
```

it works fine, but is ugly.

Is there any way to do what I'd like to? (Note: usually I use HAML, but I'm trying to get my helper working for someone else on the team who is still working in ERB for now; switching to HAML isn't a solution).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than take credit for someone else's work, I'll just point you [here.](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/01/appending-to-erb-output-from-block.html)

Comment: That doesn't really solve my problem. I don't want to change how the helper works because I want it to continue working in HAML as well. Plus, the project uses Rails, so I'm not calling ERB directly like that.